# c++ template deduction for const integer doesn't compile for my code

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, types, arguments

I've defined a template function called "Equals()" to compare integer constants between 2 `std::array`, or compare with a c-style array, like below:

```
template<typename T, typename U, size_t M, size_t N>
constexpr bool EqualsImpl(const T& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    static_assert(M == N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        if (lhs[i] != rhs[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
 
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool Equals(const T& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return EqualsImpl<T, U, size(lhs), size(rhs)>(lhs, rhs);
}
 
template<typename T, typename U, size_t N>
constexpr bool Equals(const T& lhs, const U (&rhs)[N])
{
    return EqualsImpl<T, const U (&)[N], size(lhs), N>(lhs, rhs);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    constexpr std::array<int, 4> before{1, 2, 3, 4};
    constexpr std::array<int, 4> after = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    static_assert(Equals(after, {1, 2, 3, 4}));//fail to compile
    static_assert(!Equals(before, after));//fail to compile
    return 0;
}
```

g++ compile with `--std=c++20` and prints error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'EqualsImpl'
    return EqualsImpl<T, U, size(lhs), size(rhs)>(lhs, rhs);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Equals<std::array<int, 4>, std::array<int, 4>>' requested here
    static_assert(!Equals(before, after));
note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'M'
constexpr bool EqualsImpl(const T& lhs, const U& rhs)

error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
    static_assert(!Equals(before, after));
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How to fix my code to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: `size(lhs)` is not a constant expression, so it cannot be used as a template parameter. You might want `tuple_size_v<T>` to get the compile-time size value of `std::array`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 is correct. He should write an answer and take the credit. https://godbolt.org/z/hd4v3hvTr